# breaking a section between two pages

Tags: sectioning, moderncv

I have a document with below Section command, if the size of items inside the section increase to more than a page it moves the whole section to next page, but I want to break the section between two pages, any hint?

```
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}
```

Comment: Many of the packages you need in order to make this redefinition are missing; can you post [a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3301/47522) that illustrates the problem instead of just this fragment?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this redefinition? It seems like you are renewing to almost the exact definition of `\section` with `moderncv`'s classical style...

Comment: yes this is part of moderncv classic,I just want to modify the cv template to do page breaks if the section is bigger than the size of a page,

Comment: OK - so back to my first comment: Can you post a MWE that shows the issue you are having?  I cannot recreate the problem with `moderncv`/classic, with or without your `renewcommand`.

Comment: @user52412: You're clearly using `\section` incorrectly, as you're setting the argument into a fixed-width *box* (a `\parbox` that doesn't break across the page boundary). Typically only the *title* (or heading) should form part of the section macro, with the remaining elements set *outside* the macro so there's no restriction in terms of page breaking.

Comment: @Werner This is basically the definition of `\section` from `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` except with `\renewcommand` instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand`.  If it is wrong, it is an issue with `moderncv` as a whole, not @user52412...

Comment: I think the issue may rather be with `\cvitem` and `\cventry` not allowing internal page breaks and thus forcing the entire section on the next page.

Comment: I found out that the issue is with minipage which can not be broken, I have to either not to use cventry (since it uses minipage) or have to find out another solution,

Answer (score 1):

I used below workaround: I need to find on which item the page need a break so on that item I ended the `\cventry` and started a new `\cventry` with blank parameters like: `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize}`

Answer (score 0):

`\newpage` will break a section between `\cventry`s, but as @user52412 points out if you want to page break across a `\cventry` you need to split the entry into two (the second with empty opening fields).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!